# How can I disable blocks of code in Perl like with #ifdef in C?

Tags: perl

I need to block pieces of code from a Perl script, like you can do in C with `#ifdef`s:

```
#define ANDROID true

#ifdef ANDROID
      # Execute code for Android only 
#else
      # Execute code for Linux, Windows and other platforms
#endif
```

How can I do this in Perl? We need to make as few changes as possible to our scripts (there are close to about a thousand scripts and we need to have our code as generic as possible). So I just need to know what is the best mechanism to achieve something similar to #ifdefs in C.

Comment: What do you mean by "block pieces of code?" Execute conditionally?

Comment: No I cannot use comments. We have a huge suite of perl scripts that are defined for one platform. I need to port it to other platforms with minimalistic changes, so I need to be able to set the platform like #define ANDROID and then use it to enable code to be run only on Android and not on other platforms...

Comment: Unless you rely heavily on external commands, most Perl code should be [fairly portable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html). That's the beauty of using Perl over, say, C.

Comment: Perl has variables, `if`, and `defined`... with them, all things are possible.

Comment: Using `if (defined ...)` isn't as flexible as C's `#ifdef`. For example, if the alternative chunks both define a function `foo`, you'll get a `Subroutine foo redefined` message.

Comment: If you post what you are trying to achieve with it, someone will probably give you a good alternative solution.

Comment: There are always many ways to accomplish things in Perl, so instead of asking for a tool from another language (that does not exist in Perl), you should ask about the specific portability problems that you need to solve. This is an XY-problem.

Comment: That edit is not useful. Please take the time to read my comment and respond to it, and you will get help. If not, you will not. Your call.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be any way around going through all the code and putting in `if`/`else` statements to determine what to run and what not to run. You might consider using environment variables (accessed using `$ENV{variable-name}`) as a way to decide what to run and what not to run, as opposed to setting variables in the scripts themselves.

Comment: Thanks guys! @TLP There are many APIs that are available in Android only and not in Linux etc., like device connectivity etc. We are going to figure out the porting part. Just wanted to know about this. Again, thank you so much, we appreciate your help! Thanks about the Environment Variables sir, we'll try that out too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from your comments, it seems that you are looking for a way to make your code portable, running different code when the OS changes. If so, you might use the [built-in variable `$^O`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5EO):

```
if    ($^O eq "Android") {     # run Android code
    ....
}
elsif ($^O eq "MSWin32") {     # run windows code
    ....
}
else { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: Better might be to define constants like `use constant IS_ANDROID => ($^O eq "Android");` and then use them in the conditionals `if (IS_ANDROID) { ... }`. That would allow any blocks of code destined for other platforms to be optimized away at compile time.

Comment: ... which I might add is what's happening in the C examples. The irrelevant code for other platforms doesn't get compiled.

Comment: Good call on interpreting the question. The `if` pragma is also useful, for example `use if $^O eq 'Android', 'MyModule::Android'`

Comment: Like Borodin, I'd move the OS-specific code into separate modules that share a common interface.